# Starter problem regarding file manipulation - Read > Convert > Sum > Write

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Starter problem regarding file manipulation**

Good afternoon all,

This is my very first question here.
Let me say that I am indeed ashamed of asking a beginner question : )

This is my homework for today midnight, on which I spend my whole last night but was missing something as I still cannot solve it.

I learned C a long time ago - now I am catching up and going back to the roots so chose Pyton to start strong! : )

Here is my 'simple task'

You need to load the expressions.txt file into the program. The structure of the file is such that each line represents one expression in the format:

```
4-1
9-3
```

It is necessary to write a program that reads that file, line by line, applies the given operation and writes the result together with the corresponding expression in the file output.txt.

File layout output.txt should have this written inside:

```
4-1=3
9-3=6
```

So far I've done this but this 'str' error is confusing me :

```
with open('./one.txt', 'r') as f:

lines=f.readlines()

for l in lines:

    nn=int(l[0])+int(l[2])

    mm=int(l[0])-int(l[2])

    if l(1)=='+':

        print(nn)

        f.write(nn)

    else:

        print(mm)

        f.write(mm)
```

Thank you for you time people I hope that I will repay soon!

Best regards to this community!

Nick

Comment: What is the `str` error?

Comment: Thanks for jumping in Daniel!

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  
file open close.py", line 6, in <module>
    if l(1)=='+':

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: I forged this in the end 
what do you think mate?
>>>>>

with open('izrazi.txt','r') as ulaz:
    lines = ulaz.readlines()

with open('izlaz.txt','w') as izlaz:
for l in lines:
        a=int(l[0])
        b=int(l[2])
        if l[1]=='-':
            izlaz.write(l[0]+'-'+l[2]+"="+str(int(l[0]) -int(l[2])))
        elif l[1]=='+':
            izlaz.write(l[0]+'+'+l[2]+"="+str(int(l[0]) +int(l[2])))

        izlaz.write('\n')
>>>>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your basic problem is with the following line of code:
 `if l(1)=='+':` change to  `if l[1]=='+':`.  This will correct your problem with failing to include a result.

Comment: I knew it !
Morning is always better than the night - said Jason Statham : )

Thank you for this answer ! 

Yes it has to have square bracket [] for index

Comment: Thank you a lot once again you saved my day mate !
Have a nice rest of the day and best regards!
Nick